# lua table constructor

Tags: lua

how do you make a default table and then use it when making other tables?

example

```
--default table
Button = {
 x = 0,
 y = 0,
 w = 10,
 h = 10,
 Texture = "buttonimg.png",
 onClick = function() end
}

newbutton = Button {
 onClick = function()
  print("button 1 pressed")
 end
}


newbutton2 = Button {
 x = 12,
 onClick = function()
  print("button 2 pressed")
 end
}
```

newbuttons will get y, w, h and texture set to default value but anything set in the brackets get overwritten

Comment: You can't do that, you have to augment the Button table with the "dot" operator.. Button.x = <something>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by merging Doug's answer with your original scenario, like this:

```
Button = {
   x = 0,
   y = 0,
   w = 10,
   h = 10,
   Texture = "buttonimg.png",
   onClick = function() end
}
setmetatable(Button,
         { __call = function(self, init)
                       return setmetatable(init or {}, { __index = Button })
                    end })

newbutton = Button {
   onClick = function()
                print("button 1 pressed")
             end
}

newbutton2 = Button {
   x = 12,
   onClick = function()
                print("button 2 pressed")
             end
}
```

(I actually tested this, it works.)

**Edit**: You can make this a bit prettier and reusable like this:

```
function prototype(class)
   return setmetatable(class, 
             { __call = function(self, init)
                           return setmetatable(init or {},
                                               { __index = class })
                        end })
end

Button = prototype {
   x = 0,
   y = 0,
   w = 10,
   h = 10,
   Texture = "buttonimg.png",
   onClick = function() end
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the new table's metatable's `__index` to point to `Button` it will use the default values from the `Button` table.

```
--default table
Button = {
 x = 0,
 y = 0,
 w = 10,
 h = 10,
 Texture = "buttonimg.png",
 onClick = function() end
}

function newButton () return setmetatable({},{__index=Button}) end
```

Now when you make buttons with `newButton()` they use the default values from the `Button` table.

This technique can be used for class or prototype object oriented programming. There are many examples [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientedProgramming).

Comment: The brackets around __index are superfluous.